# Excel sumif only when all are non blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have four numbers in cells A1-A4

```
34
45
9
18
```

And I want to count the sum of all four numbers:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"<>",A1:A4)
```

So far so good. How do I change the formula that it only shows the total **only** if all the numbers (A1:A4) are present. Remove A2 for a blank cell and the total should also be blank. The group of numbers will change per column, so it won't always be four.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:A4)=0,SUM(A1:A4),"")
```